# Buscar id con Razor y Ajax ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

El detalle es que en mi vista tengo el modo eliminar y buscar. Por medio de un ajax realizo la búsqueda pero no hace la acción, porque esta buscando la vista que no tiene y que es una misma donde tengo el método eliminar y que solo elimina y lo busca por  medio de ajax, alguien que me ayude que busque por medio de id y pinte los datos en los campos.

Nota:
En el ajax si cambio esto del nombre buscar por eliminar no busca elimina porque busca una vista que no existe:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@Url.Action("Buscar", "Alumno")'
    @model model.entity.Alumno    
    @{
        Layout = null;
        ViewBag.Title = "Eliminar";
    }

    <h2>Eliminar</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Eliminar", "Alumno", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div>
            <div>
                <text>ID</text>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.idAlumno)
            </div>
            <div>
                <text>Nombre</text>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nombre)
            </div>
            <div>
                <text>Apellido</text>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Apellido1)
            </div>
            <div>
                <text>Telefono</text>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Telefono1)
            </div>
            <div>
                <text>Estado</text>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.estado)
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Eliminar</button>

        <a href="#" id="bus">buscar</a>

    }


    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#bus").click(function () {
                buscarAjax();

            });

            //busco un control atraves de jquery
            function buscarAjax() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Buscar", "Alumno")',

                    data: { id: $("#idAlumno").val() },
                    type: "post",
                    cache: true,
                    success: function (retorno) {
                        //$("#contenido").html(retorno);
                        //$('td').highlight($("#idAlumno").val());
                        //$('h3').text('Se han encontrado ' + $('.highlight').length + ' coincidencias');
                        alert("A logrado la busqueda")
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Se ha producido un error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using model.Neg;
using model.entity;
using mdel.neg;



namespace WebMVC4.Controllers
{
    public class AlumnoController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Alumno/

        private AlumnoNeg objAlumnoNeg;

        private AlumnoDao objAlumnoDao;

        #region Metodo Crear Alumno
        public AlumnoController()
        {
            objAlumnoNeg = new AlumnoNeg();
        }
        //el de arriba solo te va a abrir una pantalla donde se muestren los input para que el usuario meta datos
        public ActionResult Crear()
        {

            return View();
        }
        //el segundo es el post es cuando el usuario ya lleno los input y dio click al boton submit
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Crear(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            //objAlumnoNeg.crear(objAlumno);
            AlumnoDao ins = new AlumnoDao();
            ins.crear(objAlumno);
            return RedirectToAction("inicio");
        }
        #endregion

        #region Metodo Editar Alumno
        public ActionResult Editar(string id)
        {

            AlumnoDao ins = new AlumnoDao();
            Alumno busca = new Alumno();
            busca = ins.finds(id);
            return View(busca);


            //return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Editar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AlumnoDao buscarnuevo = new AlumnoDao();
                buscarnuevo.Actualizar(objAlumno);

            }
            return RedirectToAction("inicio");
        }
        #endregion

        #region Metodo Eliminar
        public ActionResult Eliminar(string id)
        {
             AlumnoDao ins = new AlumnoDao();
            Alumno busca = new Alumno();
            busca = ins.finds(id);
            return View(busca);


            //return View();
        }
         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Buscar(string id)
        {
            AlumnoDao ins = new AlumnoDao();
            Alumno busca = new Alumno();
            busca = ins.finds(id);
            return View(busca);


            //return View();
        }
           [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Eliminar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AlumnoDao Eliminar = new AlumnoDao();
                Eliminar.Eliminar(objAlumno);


            }
            return RedirectToAction("inicio");
        }
        #endregion

        public ActionResult inicio()
        {
            List<Alumno> list = objAlumnoNeg.findAll(); // Lista de Alumnos
            return View(list);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: muestra el código de tu controlador :D

Comment: Como recién estás iniciando en el framework, te sugiero darle una mirada a este workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY espero sea de tu agrado :D

Comment: @fredyfx Man ya lo agrege el codigo de mi controlador. de igual forma gracias por el video le echaré un vistazo de paso si es posible que me puedas ayudar, por favor.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿has colocado breakpoints en los métodos a los que llamas durante su ejecución?

Comment: @fredyfx ya vi por que no estaba utilizando en el controlador JsonResult y en y regresaba un vió en lugar de un Json y de paso en mi codigo de ajax no tenia como recorrer las filas, me faltaba esto  $('#idAlumno').val(retorno.idAlumno) tenía que hacer una por cada caja de texto que quería llenar y no tomaba el valor de estado estaba en cero por que en el recorrido, había puesto [0] y era un [4] por el número de que iba a recorrer, gracias esto es solo practica espero colaborar más adelante con respuestas.

Comment: De nada bro. Coloca la respuesta, y de esta manera ayudarás a más desarrolladores :D

Comment: @fredyfx donde la coloco ya que soy nuevo en la página hasta el momento no he dado respuesta.

Comment: En la parte de abajo de esta pregunta, coloca el código que ha funcionado explicando lo que hiciste :D